# DELL Vostro 1520 bios crashed during update. now not giving even startup display

Tags: windows-7, bios, crash, dell-vostro

my dell vostro 1520 crashed while i was installing drivers of windows 7 64bit. when i tried to update the bios it suddenly hanged. it remained in that state for a long time and was not getting off even by pressing and holding the power button. i removed the battery and after again installing the battery laptop is not giving any display of startup and all the caps lock lights are blinking. what the problem is this. i am worry about my laptop. please tell me the solution

Comment: DON'T PANIC! At worst your computer is dead, but there's an extremely high chance that it can be easily fixed. On modern computers a part of BIOS is left after flash just for situations like this. You'll probably have to get a flash drive and copy some files to it and press some key combination after starting system. It should be able to pick up BIOS on flash drive and install it. On older systems, the procedure is same but uses floppy disks instead of flash drives. I don't know the exact information for Dell, but someone here must, so good luck. Hopefully someone will soon post exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder `C:\Crisis_Recovery` and extract the files from sendspace.com/file/wjy6mk to this folder
2. Download the latest BIOS for Dell Vostro 1520 and run it on PC
3. This create a temp directory for the WinPhlash app, which contain a BIOS.ROM file
4. Before closing latest BIOS installation app, make a copy of bios.rom file to `C:\Crisis_Recovery`
5. Rename the BIOS.ROM file to BIOS.WPH
6. Run the WinCris.Exe to format USB stick with Crisis Recovery Disk
7. This will write the boot record and files on to USB with specific order
8. Ensure the USB disk now contain the files minidos.sys, phlash16.exe and BIOS.WPH copied by the WinCris.Exe tool
9. Not modifying the USB stick contents, plug-in the USB stick
10. Remove the Battery
11. Hold down Left Shift key on keyboard
12. Plug in AC adapter
13. Press power button (while still holding Left Shift)
14. Keep holding Left Shift for another 10 seconds. The laptop fans should be louder
15. Release Left Shift key and let the laptop run for about 10 minutes. The laptop will auto reboot when its finished.

This process worked for me on a Dell Vostro 1520